# Minimize: How to work with specific numeric types

Tags: equation-solving, argument-patterns

This is a question about the use of symbols in [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html) and how to persuade *Mathematica* to treat them in a specific way (as integers or rationals) that I have not been able to achieve, but analysis of the results of [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html) suggests ought to be possible.

The context is this: I have the following equation and wish to find the minimum value of `t0` in closed form for a, b in terms of vx, vy, vz *without numeric values* (as you will see below I can find a minima for specific numeric values of `vx`, `vy`, `vz`).

```
t0 = g (-vz Cos[a] - vy Cos[b] Sin[a] - vx Sin[b] Sin[a])
```

In the code block below, you will see in part 1 an attempt to do this symbolically in terms of the ratio `c/d` assigned to the key variables `vx`, `vy`, `vz`; [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html) will not do it. In part 2 `vx`, `vy` and `vz` are given a specific exact numerical values and [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html) then delivers a result. However, inspection of the result clearly shows (thanks to the relative primaility of the numerators of `vx` etc.) that *Mathematica* is handling the numerators separately.

**Code**

```
Block[{g, vx, vy, vz, t0, mint,  a, b , c, d},
 t0 = g (-vz Cos[a] - vy Cos[b] Sin[a] - 
     vx Sin[b] Sin[a]); (* eqn to minimize *)
  g = 1/Sqrt[1 - (vx^2 + vx^2 + vx^2)]; (* common initialisation *)
 (* Part 1 *)
 vx = vy = vz = c/d; (* would like vx etc. elements of Rationals... how? *)
 mint = Minimize[{t0, 0 <= b < 2 Pi, 0 <= a < Pi}, {b, a}, 
   Reals]; (* fails *)
 Print["t0 minimum = ", mint];
 mint = Minimize[{t0, 0 <= b < 2 Pi, 0 <= a < Pi, , 
    c ∈ Integers, d ∈ Integers}, {b, a}, 
   Reals]; (* fails *)
 Print["t0 minimum = ", mint];
 (* Part 2 *)
 vx = 7/100; vy = 3/100; 
 vz = 11/100; (* all v made specific rationals *)
 mint = Minimize[{t0, 0 <= b < 2 Pi, 0 <= a < Pi}, {b, a}, 
   Reals]; (* succeeds *)
 Print["t0 minimum = ", mint];
 ]
```

**Result of Part 2:**

> ```
> t0 minimum = {(1/Sqrt[9853])100 (-(11/100) Cos[2 ArcTan[1/58 
>                     (-11 Sqrt[58]+Sqrt[10382])]]-3/100 
>                 Cos[2 ArcTan[1/7 (-3+Sqrt[58])]] Sin[2 ArcTan[1/58 
>                     (-11 Sqrt[58]+Sqrt[10382])]]-7/100 Sin[2 ArcTan[1/7 (-3+Sqrt[58])]] 
>                 Sin[2 ArcTan[1/58 (-11 Sqrt[58]+Sqrt[10382])]]),
>                 {b -> 2 ArcTan[1/7 (-3+Sqrt[58])], 
>                  a -> 2 ArcTan[1/58 (-11 Sqrt[58] + Sqrt[10382])]}}
> ```

where the coefficients are clearly related to the values of the denominators `vx` etc. as follows:

```
58 = 7^2 + 3^2
10382 = (7^2+3^2+11^2) * (7^2 +3^2)
```

**Question**
Is it possible to perform the minimisation symbolically and if so, how? Can one declare `vx` etc. as [`Rationals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rationals.html) directly or by assignment as the ratio of two [`Integers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integers.html)? I have tried including equivalent constraints within [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Minimize.html) (one example given in code above), but to no effect.

I also tried defining a function accepting appropriate [`Integers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integers.html) and [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reals.html), also without success.

```
f[a_Real, b_Real, c_Integer, d_Integer] := 
 g (-vz Cos[a] - vy Cos[b] Sin[a] - vx Sin[b] Sin[a]); 
vx = vy = vz = c/d;
Print["Minimize by defined function of integers = ", 
 Minimize[{f[a, b, c, d], 0 <= b < 2 Pi, 0 <= a < Pi}, {b, a}, 
  Reals]];
```

I believe that the answer to this may also have a bearing on the use of [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) and simialr functions.

Comment: Thank you for the edits: I have noted what you did and will try to do likewise myself next time. Info on/links to info on how to do other than hyperlinks to documentation (e.g. grey background on variable names in text) would be welcome.

Comment: not sure why this old question got bumped, but if you solve the problem directly (with `Reduce` ) you'll see that the restriction on the parameters being rational doesn't enter into it,ie its a moot question.

Answer (score 1):

It is very compute extreme-value problem in analysis.For example

```
Minimize[a x^2 + b x + c, x]
```

This this  simple than your cases.It just have one extreme point If a！=0.
But in your case, consider 0 <= b < 2 Pi, 0 <= a <2 Pi(the period of a and b is 2Pi, so we don't need consider boundary.Also we don't consider g).

```
Clear["Global`*"]
t0[vx_, vy_, vz_] := -vz Cos[a] - vy Cos[b] Sin[a] - vx Sin[b] Sin[a];
ExtremePoint[vx_, vy_, vz_] := 
Select[Table[
    Solve[{D[t0[vx, vy, vz], a] == 0, D[t0[vx, vy, vz], b] == 0}, {a, 
        b}][[All, All, 2]] /. {C[1] -> i, C[2] -> j}, {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}] 
        // Flatten[#, 2] &, 
  Function[{a, b}, (Not[NumericQ[a]] || 0 <= a <= 2 Pi) && (Not[NumericQ[b]] ||
     0 <= b <= 2 Pi)] @@ # &]
ExtremePoint[1, 1, 1] // Length
ExtremePoint[vx, vy, vz] // Length
```

If vx=vy=vz=1,we just need consider 10 points.But if we don't know any about vx vy vz, we need consider 54 points ,and they all are symbolic expressions！

But there is a good thing that the values in extreme points is too simple.

```
t0[vx, vy, vz] /. {a -> #1, b -> #2} & @@@ ExtremePoint[vx, vy, vz] 
   //Simplify // DeleteDuplicates 
(*{Sqrt[vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2], -Sqrt[vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2], -vz, vz}*)
```

So the minimize of function is

```
min[vx_, vy_, vz_] := -Sqrt[vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2]
```

let us test it

```
testdata = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {10, 3}]
min @@@ testdata
Minimize[{t0[##],0<=a<=Pi,0<=b<=2Pi}, {a, b}] & @@@ testdata
Minimize[{t0[##],0<=a<=2Pi,0<=b<=2Pi}, {a, b}] & @@@ testdata
```

It is just correct when we allow 0<=a<=2Pi because we don't consider the boundary(For example a=0)

```
Minimize[{t0[6.057, 0.972, 3.014], 0 < a < Pi}, {a, b}]
```

the position of extreme points is complex.

```
{t0[vx, vy, vz] /. {a -> #1, b -> #2}, {a->#1,a-> #2}} & @@@
     ExtremePoint[vx, vy, vz]// Simplify // DeleteDuplicates;
Select[%, #[[1]] == -Sqrt[vx^2 + vy^2 + vz^2] &] // Length
```

Comment: Thanks... I will look at this in detail in the morning. In the meantime, just to mention that I also tried the derivative approach to extrema (with g) and maybe I was too impatient... I only allowed Mma about 10 minutes to solve. We shall see! Good food for thought.

Comment: I appreciate VERY much what you have done and I am learning a lot from it, but I was trying to understand how Minimize could work with numeric rationals and not symbolic rationals when numeric numerator and denominator elements seemed to propagate cleanly through Minimize. I did not mean to ask "how to minimise" in general, I mean "How to use Minimize" in this case. (and if it can't be used, to understand specifically why not, general complexity would be too non-specific an answer.) I would appreciate advice from anyone on whether to close this Q and re-ask or do something else